# Community Promotion Ads - 2H 2011

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2012](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1030/community-promotion-ads-1h-2012)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool site-related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- scripts packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. This question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](http://meta.status.stackexchange.com/ads/display/893).

Answer (score 10):

[image: @StackStats]

Comment: As per Grace note suggestion we should include the suggestion to read our blog too.

Answer (score 5):

Probably new tagline would be great, but for now I'll repost Shane's ad:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Help this community grow!]

Comment: Mathematica is a great tool for statistical graphics, theoretical stats, and even some applications. :-) This site (still in beta) boasts some impressive answers to stats- and graphics- related questions: check it out.

Comment: shouldn't this be posted [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1030/6109) instead?

Comment: This question should probably be closed as a duplicate of the [2012 version](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1030/4764).  This way the old ads will be kept (in case someone wants to copy them over), and people won't post in the old thread my mistake (I didn't notice that it was last year's thread either).

Comment: Thanks for flagging this: I have reposted the ad in the current thread (for 1H 2012) and closed this one.  (We need a better mechanism for proposing ads...)