# Community Promotion Ads - 1H 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for home improvement
- interesting in-site activities and events
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1030).

Answer (score 12):

[image: StackStats Twitter]

Answer (score 11):

[image: arXiv.org -- open access to over 700 000 e-prints]

Answer (score 11):

[image: International Year of Statistics 2013]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Help this community grow!]

Comment: (+1) But, *funnest*. Really? :-)

Comment: @cardinal Yes, it makes me wince. It's almost as bad as the Apple site's logo--but not quite as bad, because the grammatical solecism is so *obvious* here.  Apple's error is not only intentional, but perhaps too subtle for many, which IMHO is an insidious thing to do to our language.

Comment: @cardinal yeah, it makes me twitch, too, and I helped approve it. But, whatever works.

Comment: @cardinal the slogan was my doing. Yes, it's deliberate. Ironically, I heard the word used by Steve Jobs in a keynote once. The grammatically correct version would have sounded flat. It got your attention, didn't it?